Spring Boot Kotlin Exposed: Transaction synchronization is not active
I try to use Kotlin Expose in parallel with JPA in Spring Boot application. Here is example of controller:
@RestController
@RequestMapping("sys/sys-system")
class ExposedController {

    @GetMapping("try-exposed")
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    fun tryExposed(): String {
        return getFromDb()
    }


    fun getFromDb() = transaction {
        MessageDefaultTable.selectAll().joinToString { it[MessageDefaultTable.text] }
    }
}

When I try to do request I get the error:
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Transaction synchronization is not active
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationManager.getSynchronizations(TransactionSynchronizationManager.java:292)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationUtils.triggerBeforeCompletion(TransactionSynchronizationUtils.java:106)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.triggerBeforeCompletion(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:926)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:773)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:711)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:660)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:410)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119)

If I remove @Transactional(readOnly = true) everything is OK, but in real application with repositories @Transaction is used in many service methods, which work with JPA/
How can I say for Spring TransactionManager about Exposed transaction?
Here is my Exposed Config:
@Configuration
@Conditional(ExposedConfigCondition::class)
class ExposedConfig(applicationContext: ApplicationContext): ExposedAutoConfiguration(applicationContext) {

    @Bean
    override fun databaseConfig(): DatabaseConfig {

        return DatabaseConfig {
            this.useNestedTransactions = true
            this.explicitDialect = PostgreSQLDialect()
            this.defaultReadOnly = true
        }
    }
}

Spring Boot: 3.1.2
Exposed: 0.40.1
I tried to write getFromDb() another way
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
    fun getFromDb() = MessageDefaultTable.selectAll().joinToString { it[MessageDefaultTable.text] }

But it leads to another error
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No transaction in context.
    at org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.transactions.TransactionManager$Companion.current(TransactionApi.kt:130)
    at org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.AbstractQuery.getTransaction(AbstractQuery.kt:9)
    at org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.AbstractQuery.iterator(AbstractQuery.kt:61)

